# Subsetting data.table column through a variable list

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
dt<- data.table(V1=c(1L,2L),
                V2=LETTERS[1:3],
                V3=1:12)
```

I want to subset the first and second columns like this:

```
dt2 <- dt[, c("V1", "V2")]
```

Works fine. However, when trying...

```
chosen.cols <- c("V1", "V2")
dt[,(chosen.cols),with = F]
```

... it only works appending the `'with=F'`, otherwise it returns:

```
[1] "V1" "V2"
```

1) Why do we need `'with ='`?

2) What exactly `'with ='` implies to the code?

Thank you.